# Applying Hadamard's Three Lines Theorem to prove that $f(z) = f(r) (z/r)^k$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am currently stuck on a complex analysis exercise, which I find quite difficult, here it is:

"Let $0<r<R$, define the Annulus as $A_{r,R} := \{z \in \mathbb{C}: r<|z|<R \}$. Let $f:\overline{A_{r,R}} \rightarrow \overline{A_{\tilde {r},\tilde {R}}}$ be a holomorphic function on $A_{r,R}$, with $0<r<R<\infty$, $0<\tilde{r}<\tilde{R}<\infty$, such that: $|z| =r \implies |f(z)|=\tilde{r}, |z| = R \implies |f(z)| = \tilde{R}$. Show that there is a natural number $k$, such that $f(z) = f(r) (z/r)^k$ for all $z \in \overline{A_{r,R}}$."

The exercise has a tip: "Apply Hadamard's Three Lines Theorem on an appropriate function".

I have read something about Hadamard's Three Circle Theorem, which has similar conditions, however, it only says something about the supremums of $|f|$ on specific circles, but here we want to say something about $f$, so I'm not sure if it's possible to apply it here.

My first and only idea was to consider a holomorphic function $g :  S \rightarrow \overline{A_{r,R}}$, which bijectively maps the strip $ S := \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}: r \leq \Re(z) \leq R\}$ to  $\overline{A_{r,R}}$ in a "Riemann-way". Then we could consider a map $ \gamma: S \rightarrow \overline{A_{\tilde {r},\tilde {R}}}$, $\gamma = f \circ g$. We know that $f$ is bounded by $\tilde{R}$, so $\gamma$ is a bounded holomorphic function, if we define $\Gamma(x) := \sup \{\gamma(z): \Re(z) = x \}$, we can apply Hadamard's TLT, so $\Gamma(x) \leq \Gamma(r)^{1-x} \Gamma(R)^x = \tilde{r}^{1-x}\tilde{R}^x$ $\forall x \in [r,R]$. That's all I have. But what now? I don't see any way to continue, what else could I try, does someone have a tip? Thanks in advance!

Edit: We got a solution for this problem, but coming up with the function $g$ doesnt seem very trivial, but the key idea is to apply the Three Lines Theorem on the function

$$g(z) := f(r \exp(z \ln(R/r))) / (\tilde{r} \exp(z \ln(\tilde{R} / \tilde{r})))$$

And on its reciprocal $1/g(z)$ to show that $|g(z)| = 1$. If anyone is interested I can give more details.